Excel VBA: Display a "MsgBox" to see the current state of a ribbon checkbox
I'll try to explain this problem as simple as possible. So I have created a checkBox through the Excel.officeUI file located in "C:\Users<your_username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office" containing the following line:
<!-- New checkbox -->
<mso:checkBox id="checkBox1" label="Is pressed?" onAction="CheckBoxChanged"/>

This checkBox will run the macro "CheckBoxChanged" when activated, and it should display its current state (whether it is pressed or not):
Sub CheckBoxChanged(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
  If pressed Then
    MsgBox "The checkbox is checked.", vbInformation
  Else
    MsgBox "The checkbox is not checked.", vbInformation
  End If
End Sub

Nonetheless, I haven't been able to make it work, as clicking the checkBox won't activate the macro. Does anyone know why?
Thanks in advance!
NOTE 1:
It seems the problem may be related to the .officeUI file. If I don't have any macros in my current workbook, and I click the checkBox, it should display the following warning:
"Cannot run the macro 'CheckBoxChanged'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."
However, it doesn't display any message. Here is the officeUI code:
<mso:customUI xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>
  <mso:ribbon>
    <mso:tabs>

    <!-- New tab -->
    <mso:tab id='tab' label='3D Section'>
  
    <!-- New group -->
    <mso:group id='group' label='Catalogs and specifications' autoScale='false'>
      
      <!-- New checkbox -->
      <mso:checkBox id="checkBox1" label="Is pressed?" onAction="CheckBoxChanged" />

      <!-- Close all -->
    </mso:group>
  </mso:tab>
</mso:tabs>
</mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>


Is this the single macro related to the question which you have? You firstly have to set the iRibbon object and the checkbox change event only after invalidating of this object for the respective control...

@FaneDuru It is. Moreover, I think the problem is related to the officeUI file. If I don't have any macros in my workbook, when clicking the checkBox it should display the warning "Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook", but it doesnt.

Without setting a macro to run when the ribbon is loaded (OnLoad) you will never do anything with any control, I am afraid. But why did you choose this method of adding your control? This is the old method affected by some others workbooks, add-ins having their own custom ribbon and needs switching to the former ribbon file. It is much safer/better to use OfficeRibbonXEditor and do it specifically for the workbook you want. There are plenty of examples on this community... Also, links where from to download it.

I'm afraid I can't use OfficeRibbonXEditor, since I don't have website-download permissions in the company I work for.  This is the only method I can use at the moment. Appart from that, I tried following the steps in this video but the problem still persists:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-t0ag8fg5U

I am afraid I cannot help on the issue using this method. I tried once, some years before and it was enough... I do not like it, I will never recommend it to anybody. No any interest to dig again...

I can feel your pain man.

Aleluia........

Would you consider making these Ribbon controls and the associated code in the macro file itself instead of the officeUI file? Then you will only see the controls when the file containing the specific macros is active. That way you also avoid changing the Excel's outlook overall.

The ribbon needs to be shared through every excel file (hence modifying the officeUI specifically). It appears the checkbox element is the only one I can't get to work. Changing it for a button will execute any macro though...
